# Loading file depending on what is present in HTML / script

Tags: javascript, html

MathJax has a new version and loading this is incompatible with the old version. For generated code we need to load the right startup file depending on which file is present.

Currently we have in the html code a line, for version 2, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="../../MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
```

for version 3 this should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="../../MathJax/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

on the MathJax directory either `MathJax.js` or `tex-chtml.js` is present, but when the code is created it is unknown which file is present.

It would be nice when there is a construct where the presence can be tested and when present this file is loaded as if the `src=` was present.

So far I haven't found anything in this direction.

NOTE: the example is with `../../MathJax` but the reference can also be to a CDN, so like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.6/MathJax.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**
A possible solution would be to load both files, but in e.g. the "Firefox Inspector" this will lead to a message like:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///.../MathJax/tex-chtml.js”.
```

**Edit:**
when trying (based on the comment regarding https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ from @RobbyCornelissen):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.6/tex-chtml.js")
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
       $.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.6/MathJax.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    });
  });
</script>
```

it works!!, but I get the warnings (the tex-chtml.js does not exist on the indicated position):

```
The script from “https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.6/tex-chtml.js?_=1571844722744” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
aa_8h.html
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.6/tex-chtml.js?_=1571844722744”.
```

When using though the local version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getScript( "../../MathJax_2.1/MathJax.js")
    .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
       $.getScript( "../../MathJax_2.1/tex-chtml.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    });
  });
</script>
```

I get the warnings (MathJax.js exists on the indicated position):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///D:/speeltuin/MathJax_2.1/MathJax.js?_=1571844626418. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///D:/speeltuin/MathJax_2.1/tex-chtml.js?_=1571844626419. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

and there is no file loaded.

Comment: If only one is present, why just not try to load both? Only one will get loaded, and the other request will just error out with a 404. This should be transparent to the user.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question, this would be possible but in e.g. the "Firefox Inspector" one gets a warning like `Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///.../MathJax/tex-chtml.js”.`

Comment: Is that a problem? If so, just write a little JavaScript function that takes an array of possible locations, sends an AJAX request to attempt to retrieve it, and load the first one for which the AJAX request succeeds.

Comment: I don't like to get warnings, they will always backfire and when users see them they think that something is wrong. There is no fixed set of directories / CDNs, user can define them, but how would this `ajax` code look like (no experience with it).

Comment: I feel bad recommending jQuery in 2019, but jQuery lets you do it [like this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Fairly trivial to implement something similar yourself, or find a more elegant library that does the same.

Comment: Thanks, we load jquery so I'll have later on today a go at it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen 1) any idea about how to suppress the warnings about not able to load the url? 2) any ideas how to solve the CORS problem in case of loading a file?